# How to add a separate header template only for product listing page

Tags: layout, template

```
<reference name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/html/header_b.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

This code will overwrite the header.phtml with new phtml file,

But i want this rewrite only in my product listing pages.I don't want to overwrite my header html files in product description page

How to achieve this
I am adding this as layout updates from my admin panel

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
<my_handle> <!-- create custom handle to avoid duplication -->
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/html/header_b.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</my_handle>

<catalog_category_default> <!-- apply handle to default category handle-->
    <update handle="my_handle" />
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered> <!-- apply handle to layered category handle-->
    <update handle="my_handle" />
</catalog_category_layered>
<catalogsearch_result_index> <!-- apply handle to quick search handle-->
    <update handle="my_handle" />
</catalogsearch_result_index>
<catalogsearch_advanced_result> <!-- apply handle to advanced search results handle-->
    <update handle="my_handle" />
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<my_handle> <!-- create custom handle to avoid duplication -->
<reference name="header">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/html/header_b.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

make on template and call this new header and assign this template what you want.